# Add a url to a string in Python

Tags: python, string, url

I want to be able to assign a url to a portion of a string in Python.

E.g.

StrVar = "This is my test string"

I want to add a url, say "www.stackoverflow.com" to the word "test.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()`:

```
StrVar = "This is my test string"
StrVar = StrVar.replace("test", "www.stackoverflow.com")
print(StrVar)
```

Output is `This is my www.stackoverflow.com string`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain myself correctly. I want the url hidden, i.e. leave the word test in the string but assign the url, possibly underlining or changing the colour so people know it's a link.

Comment: Do you mean add a hyperlink? I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: A hyperlink as you describe it is a graphical element such as you might find on a website. You can't have them in a text file, because a text file is just text.